# java equivalent of scipy.linalg.eigh with parameter optional matrix

Tags: python, java, scipy, linear-algebra

I need calculate eigenvalue in java. And I need the relative matrix which is like the parameter b in  scipy.linalg.eigh.

```
def eigh(a, b=None, lower=True, eigvals_only=False, overwrite_a=False,
     overwrite_b=False, turbo=True, eigvals=None, type=1,
     check_finite=True, subset_by_index=None, subset_by_value=None,
     driver=None):
```

---

```
Method description
Solve a standard or generalized eigenvalue problem for a complex
Hermitian or real symmetric matrix.

Find eigenvalues array ``w`` and optionally eigenvectors array ``v`` of
array ``a``, where ``b`` is positive definite such that for every
eigenvalue λ (i-th entry of w) and its eigenvector ``vi`` (i-th column of
``v``) satisfies::

                  a @ vi = λ * b @ vi
    vi.conj().T @ a @ vi = λ
    vi.conj().T @ b @ vi = 1

In the standard problem, ``b`` is assumed to be the identity matrix.

Parameters
----------
a : (M, M) array_like
    A complex Hermitian or real symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues and
    eigenvectors will be computed.
b : (M, M) array_like, optional
    A complex Hermitian or real symmetric definite positive matrix in.
    If omitted, identity matrix is assumed
```

I have tried apache.math. All of them only offer the similar eig method without parameter. Is there any equivalent in java?

Comment: What does this b parameter do ? Why is it necessary ?

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich I think it’s kind of reference matrix.As it says, identity matrix would be reference matrix if b is none

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the [OjAlgo](https://www.ojalgo.org/) library is likely to have what you need.

Here's an [example](https://www.ojalgo.org/2019/08/generalised-eigenvalue-problems/) with eigenvalues.

```
        var dim = 2;
        
        Primitive64Store mtrxA = Primitive64Store.FACTORY.make(2, 2);
        mtrxA.fillOne(0, 0, 4.0);
        mtrxA.fillOne(0, 1, 0.0);
        mtrxA.fillOne(1, 0, 0.0);
        mtrxA.fillOne(1, 1, 1.0);

        System.out.println(mtrxA);

        Primitive64Store mtrxB = Primitive64Store.FACTORY.make(2, 2);

        mtrxB.fillOne(0, 0, 0.6);
        mtrxB.fillOne(0, 1, -0.5);
        mtrxB.fillOne(1, 0, -0.5);
        mtrxB.fillOne(1, 1, 0.7);

        System.out.println(mtrxB);
        /*
         * There are several generalisations. 3 are supported by ojAlgo, specified by the enum:
         * Eigenvalue.Generalisation This factory method returns the most common alternative.
         */
        Eigenvalue.Generalised<Double> generalisedEvD = Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.makeGeneralised(mtrxA);
        // Generalisation: [A][V] = [B][V][D]

        // Use 2-args alternative

        generalisedEvD.computeValuesOnly(mtrxA, mtrxB);
        generalisedEvD.decompose(mtrxA, mtrxB);

        // Eigenvectors in the columns
        System.out.println("Eigenvectors are in the columns below");
        System.out.println(generalisedEvD.getV());

        // Eigenvalues on the diagonal
        System.out.println("Eigenvalues are on the diagonal in the matrix below");
        System.out.println(generalisedEvD.getD());

        // You can also transpose the matrices with this lib
        var transposed = mtrxB.transpose();
        // Printing out the transposed matrix
        System.out.println(transposed.toString());
```

**EDIT:** Here's a [working code example](https://github.com/klezovics/java-generalized-eigenvalue-problem/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/javabootpad/EigenValueTest.java), which solves the problem for you specific data case.

Comment: I can not find the same method in this lib. There is one with similar description. But the result does not match to the python one. Any suitable method suggest?

Comment: What do you want to do concretely ?

Comment: I update the question description that shows clearly function of this method

Comment: generalisedEvD.decompose(mtrxA, mtrxB); // Use one of these methods, not both

This one seems to be the one you are looking for

Comment: yeah，I tried this one. But the result is not same with python one.

Comment: Which matrices are you using specifically, can you send as text the input and expected output ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239031/discussion-between-arthur-klezovich-and-wl-gig).

Comment: I update the info you need in chat

Comment: Added info to chat and here

Comment: it works XD. one more thing, the result needs to transposition

Comment: Nice to hear that it works. I'll send you the link to how to do transposition in it.

Comment: Added code example. See at the very bottom the code to do the transpose. Its simple and one method call. Can I have my bounty now, please ? :)

Comment: due to the bounty time lime, I just gave it to you XD

Comment: Thanks man ! :) Always a pleasure to work with my chinese friends :D

Answer (score 1):

[EJML](https://ejml.org) has flags to avoid computing eigenvalues and you can select different variants. [JavaDoc for the factory.](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/dense/row/factory/DecompositionFactory_DDRM.html#eig(boolean,boolean))

Comment: I expect the parameter of reference matrix instead of flags